# Copy / duplicate a wiki page from one site collection to another one

Tags: copy-item, copy-content

I would like to know how can I make this action in SP 2013 ?

Hoping your help,

Regards,

EM.

Answer (score 5):

You can download the page from site collection source, and upload the page in site collection destination.

Or you can make a granular backup of the pages library (site collection source) in Central Administration, and restore the pages library in site collection destination if you don't have any other pages you need to save in that library.

Or you can backup the entire site collection using Backup-SPSite powershell script and run Restore-SPSite to another web application (with another content database) in the same farm.

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish by copy a page, library or site.

Comment: Your answer is definitely better than mine

Comment: @SteffPoint Thank you. But you have a good answer yourself, and I think we complement each other with different methods of doing the same thing :-)

Comment: Hi & thx but when I create a very simple page and I try to export/Import (from A to B) I got an error : Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EmbeddedFormField' does not have a public property named 'div' Content and structure only works for an action in the same site collection (not between both)
:'\

Comment: @HarryUp Maybe you don't have all the solutions installed, or features activated in destination site collection? Looks like that from your error message...

Comment: Hi & many thanks Benny, it works for you ? the drag & drop solution from the sitepages library site collection A to the sitepages library site collection B ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I would do, copy and paste the page using two sessions of SharePoint designer.

Open the first site in SharePoint designer and navigate to the wiki page in the site pages library. Then do the same for the second site. Copy and Paste the page from one site to another.

*Also note that any web parts that rely on lists or data from the first site collection may not work as expected.*

Comment: It worked for me. But I had to copy the files one by one in order to make them work properly on the new site.

Comment: Note that if you do this between SP 2010 and 2016, when you try open the page in 2016, it will give you an error:  `Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.EmbeddedFormField' does not have a public property named 'div'.`

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar answer on Stackoverflow and changed it for your requirements:

One of the options could be to save a Wiki site [as a site template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj938033(v=office.15).aspx). Then deploy it in a site collection and to create new sites from it. But unfortunately since Wiki site is *Publishing based* site, [it is not supported to Save Site as Template](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2492356).

But there is another option - [moving sites via Site Content and Structure](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/work-with-site-content-and-structure-HA010131723.aspx#BM5):

Steps:

1. Go to `Site Settings`, then `Content and structure (under Site
   Administration)`
2. Select site you would like to move and `copy` action in the context menu
3. In the `Copy` dialog select a destination (parent site) and
   then click `OK`

That's it.

See reference post here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25103249/how-to-move-wiki-pages-between-sites-in-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Doesn't this action delete the page from the source?

Comment: You're right. Instead of "move" he should use "copy". Let me fix it :)

Comment: Re,
The content and structure menu works fine only for one site collection.
Unless I'm mistaken, you can't select another site collection.
I need and would like to copy my page from the site collection A ton the site collection B.